# JSON VBA Parse to Excel

Tags: json, vba, excel, web-scraping

I got some JSON parsing working. I use VBA to parse a JSON code from my webserver, write that to cell A1 at my Excel Worksheet. But I don't get this to convert into the other cells.

Here is my JSON sample:

```json
{
    "@type":["IN.areaList.1","OII.list.1"],
    "@self":"/bereiche",
    "list":[
          {"@type":["IN.bereich.1"],
           "@self":"/1.1.Bereich.2.7",
           "scha":false,
           "trlState":"",
           "oiischa":false,
           "readyTo1":false,
           "readyTo2":false,
           "numberOfBypassedDevices":0,
           "test":"",
           "TestActive":false,
           "chModeActive":false,
           "incs":[]}
            ]
}
```

This is my Sub, it is working for another sample:

```vb
Sub JsonToExcelExample()

    Dim jsonText As String
    Dim jsonObject As Object
    Dim item As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Remote")
    jsonText = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
    i = 3
    ws.Cells(2, 1) = "Color"
    ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Hex Code"
    For Each item In jsonObject("0")
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = item("color")
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("value")
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

How this VBA code should be changed so that the above JSON sample to be placed on the worksheet like a table?

Comment: To get propper formating for your code you have to have 4 spaces infront of every line that you want to be displayed as code.

Comment: Can you give ma one example. First i want to get output from TestActive

Comment: http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parse-json-safer-with-jsonparse-and.html

Comment: You may apply `JSON.ToArray` and output result arrays to worksheet, take a look at [code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+JSON.ToArray). Show the expected output for the sample you have.

Comment: Your JSON and VBA code seem not to be related?  What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the below example. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()
    Dim vResult

    ' Retrieve question #50068973 HTML content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068973", False
        .send
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    ' Extract JSON sample from the question
    sJSONString = "{" & Split(sJSONString, "<code>{", 2)(1)
    sJSONString = Split(sJSONString, "</code>", 2)(0)
    ' Parse JSON sample
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON"
        End
    End If
    ' Convert raw JSON to array and output to worksheet #1
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    ' Flatten JSON
    JSON.Flatten vJSON, vResult
    ' Convert flattened JSON to array and output to worksheet #2
    JSON.ToArray vResult, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The output on the worksheet #1 for the raw sample you provided is as follows:

[image: raw]

And there is the flattened sample output on the worksheet #2:

[image: flattened]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: I found this to be very slow on large data sets. It looks like: "Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData" is taking all the time. Any suggestions? I tried Application.ScreenUpdating = False and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Comment: @Marius AFAIK `Output2DArray` uses the fastest method available in VBA.

Comment: Edit to above comment: Apologies, it was actually JSON.Parse that takes all the time. Any way to speed it up?

Comment: @Marius IMO better you to post a new question where you can describe the performance issue you encountered.