# VBA get real time from internet get error: The download of the specified resource has failed

Tags: vba, api

I want to get real-time from the internet to Excel file, on my computer it does not work but on another one it works.

The error on my computer is:

> "The download of the specified resource has failed."

```
Function GetUCTTimeDate() As Date
Dim UTCDateTime As String
Dim arrDT() As String
Dim http As Object
Dim UTCDate As String
Dim UTCTime As String

Const NetTime As String = "https://www.time.gov/"

On Error Resume Next
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
On Error GoTo 0

http.Open "GET", NetTime & Now(), False, "", ""
http.send

UTCDateTime = http.getResponseHeader("Date")
UTCDate = Mid(UTCDateTime, InStr(UTCDateTime, ",") + 2)
UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
UTCTime = Mid(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") + 1)
UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
GetUCTTimeDate = DateValue(UTCDate) + TimeValue(UTCTime)
End Function
```

Comment: The code works with no errors on my workstation. My only guess is that you're encountering occasional network issues routing your request to the specified URL.

Comment: Do you think that the code depends on IE version?

Comment: My guess is no, but it's reasonable idea to keep in mind. I would suggest continuing to test with other websites and/or code to see if the problem persists or changes (or goes away). A web search for [vba rest api](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+rest+api&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US752&oq=vba+rest+api&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3694j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) can lead you to some examples [to test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38258514/4717755)

Answer (score 0):

I also got exactly the same problem before.. it worked fine on my pc but error on the other pc.

to solve the problem, dim the function "As String" not "As Date"

```
Public Function GetUCTTimeDate() As String
```

and remove "DateValue" from `GetUCTTimeDate = DateValue(UTCDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It occured when I changed the format date of my computer, from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy. I was trying to solve it, and the solution that I found was passing the date to the sheet and then take it again.

```
Function GetUCTTimeDate() As Date
    Dim UTCDateTime As String
    Dim arrDT() As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim UTCDate As String
    Dim UTCTime As String

    Const NetTime As String = "https://www.time.gov/"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    On Error GoTo 0

    http.Open "GET", NetTime & Now(), False, "", ""
    http.send

    UTCDateTime = http.getResponseHeader("Date")
    UTCDate = Mid(UTCDateTime, InStr(UTCDateTime, ",") + 2)
    UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
    Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C2") = UTCDate   'Here I passed to the sheet
    UTCTime = Mid(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") + 1)
    UTCDate = Left(UTCDate, InStrRev(UTCDate, " ") - 1)
    GetUCTTimeDate = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("C2") 'Getting again the date

End Function
```