# How to get the image url from a webpage

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to get the image url from a website, the example page is `https://ecat.aptiv.com/product/15304719`. Using Chrome inspecting feature, I detect the image is inside class `ProductDetailHeader col-xs-2` and the `src` is

```
<... src="https://ecat.aptiv.com/images/default-source/ecatalog-images/part_gt-2-8-ph-a-001-png.png?sfvrsn=1d1e47d5_0">
```

However, when I try to extract the url, there are just null values for `src`

```
 Dim elements As Object
 Dim element As Object
 Set elements = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ProductDetailHeader col-xs-2")
   For Each element In elements
        Debug.Print element.getAttribute("src")
   Next
```

I have no problem getting other values but I cannot figure out why I cannot get the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image URL is generated using angular JS. If you view the source it will display:

```
<div class="ProductDetailHeader col-xs-2" style="width: 20%; float: right;" ng-show="ProductDetail.MainImage">
            <img ng-src="{{ProductDetail.MainImage.URL}}" alt="{{ProductDetail.MainImage.Name}}" />
        </div>
```

There is an alterative way to get the image url, which is by calling their API directly
by preforming a HTTP Get to `https://ecat.aptiv.com/json/eCatalogSearch/SearchProducts?filter=All&options=&pageSize=12&search=15304719` (which will return JSON).

Comment: thank you very much, I paste and API and it looks much cleaner than going to the webpage. So I think I will take your suggestion, the issue is that I do not know any about Json and how to integrate it into VB Excel so I will need some additional learning.

Comment: I've never had to call an API from VB Excel. However this may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246789/how-do-we-use-restful-apis-from-excel-macros-vba

Comment: thank, this is definitely much much faster than using web object that I could only think of.

Comment: how could you figure out the hyperlink that can give the JSON response `https://ecat.aptiv.com/json/eCatalogSearch/SearchProducts?filter=All&options=&pageSize=12&search=15304719` ? I am trying to figure this out with `https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0334724802` but the source does not really gives me the hyperlink so I can get the JSON response.

Comment: In Google Chrome, press F12, go to network tab and then look for types that are "xhr". Unfortunately it looks like molex.com binds their data to the UI, which means you''ll have to do some sort of web scraping