# How to implement in VBA a REST(ful) API for a moodle Database?

Tags: vba, rest, ms-access, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to handle moodle data from our schools MS-Access database using VBA-code to post xml.objects that I also successfully used for an API communicating with Telegram (the messenger service).

I tried to implement the following code from an example for using the RESTful-API into my VBA-code:

`curl -X POST \ -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \ -H "Accept: application/json" \ -H 'Authorization: {token}' \ -d'options[ids][0]=6' \ "https://localhost/webservice/restful/server.php/core_course_get_courses"`

This is how my VBA-code looks like:

```
Private Sub btnTestMoodleApi_Click()
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strResult As String
Dim strPostData As String
Dim strURL As String
Dim strToken As String

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

strURL = xxx

strToken = xxx

strPostData = "options[ids][0]=432"
With objRequest
  .Open "POST", strURL & "/webservice/restful/server.php?wstoken={" & strToken & "}/core_course_get_courses"
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", " application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
  .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "{strToken}"
  .Send (strPostData)
strResult = .responseText
Debug.Print strResult
End With
End Sub
```

The error I get in MS-Access is rather useless to me (also changing some aspects as described below did not change the error message):

" -runtime error 2147483638: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

I suspect the following error sources:

a) I thought that "-H" means header, but the ".setRequestHeader" method just accepts one variable and value. I guessed maybe I can use it several times. But I am not sure if that works or how else I could declare a header in a xml.object.

b) I guess that "-d" means data, I had no idea what to do with it, thus I put into the .send() method. I think that is where the html body goes. I could be utterly wrong...

c) I nested the token for my API into the URL, because I saw it like this in another example. However the original instructions for the moodle-plugin do not have the token in the URL (only in the Authorization Header). I tried both ways, it did not work either way...

I would be really glad if someone with experience in vba could help me, how to implement API instructions into the vba code or at least point me in the right direction. Actually I do not really need this particular core function but the more complex ones to create courses etc. But I thought it was best to start with an easy example as I don't know much about API/ xml/ php/ html etc..

Thanks for reading

Arndt David

Comment: Your URL looks malformed. There's a slash after the question mark. You likely want `/webservice/restful/server.php/core_course_get_courses?wstoken={" & strToken & "}`, however, your CURL request doesn't contain this `?wstoken` thing at all. Also, anything involving https and localhost is bound to lead to trouble, you shouldn't have a valid HTTPS cert for localhost on your system.

Comment: @ErikA, "shouldn't" or "should" have valid HTTPS cert?

Comment: @June7 Shouldn't. Certs are granted by a certificate authority, they can't grant anyone a certificate for "localhost" since everyone has their own "localhost", so it can only be a self-signed certificate. Because you're using VBA, you have to manually trust that certificate. And once you do, you have a self-signed certificate for localhost in your certificate store which makes it much easier for programs including malware to intercept or redirect https traffic. Often, it's a much better idea to fiddle with the hosts file and having a name on that cert if you do local testing.

Comment: Can you point us to the API documentation for the **specific** API you are trying to call please?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responses.
@QHarr This is were I got the code from: https://moodle.org/plugins/webservice_restful

Comment: @ErikA Unfortunately I am not familiar with much of the terminology used. The security token I put into the URL was generated in the moodle files. It also in the authorization header, what do you mean by CURL-Request? The string I entered in the .send method?

Comment: @ErikA I also do not understand your remark on a certificate. I am not sending a request to the localhost on my machine but to a webserver where my moodle database is at. I also thought that the token posted in the authorization header is the only form of validation I need.

Comment: By the way, it seems like I need to implement a loop to wait for results:
`While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
Wend`
No there is no more error message, however the return value is NULL.

Comment: This is where I found the advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246789/how-do-we-use-restful-apis-from-excel-macros-vba

Comment: @QHarr The problem is still not solved, as there is simply no return value. I am sure that the course with the specified ID in the criteria `options[ids][0]=432` that I send with the body exists and according to the documentation the function should work as simple as that. Do I maybe somehow need another formatting of the body? Or do I have to implement the criteria some other way? Maybe also in the URL? How can I test if at least the connection to my webservice on the moodle webserver worked?

Comment: Hiya, Will try to spend some time on this over next few days

Comment: @QHarr If you have some spare time, thank's for looking into it: I have changed the command from post to get (as I figured, it's a command to retrieve information). Now I get a repsonse, but it's an error that the URL cannot be found. I'm quite sure it's correct however.
`w<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) SVN/1.9.5 OpenSSL/1.0.2u Server at www.web289.s247.goserver.host Port 443</address>
</body></html>`

Comment: @Harr how can i make sure that I have the correct path on the server? I used filezilla to check if the folder-path and the called server.php file exist, I saw that I missed out on some details in the path, and corrected them but still it says URL not found... By the way "POST" or "GET" now does not make a difference anymore. Both return the same error.

Comment: @QHarr Ok, I figured out what was wrong whith the URL, I am now looking into the locallib.php file because of an authorization header problem. If I cannot make any sens of it, I would open a new post. Thank's anyhow!

Comment: For some reason I didn't receive notifications of your comments above. Apologies

Comment: @QHarr No problem, as the first steps to my solution where rather basics. However now I encountered a follow up problem I find a bit more complex. I posted it in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580320/convert-curl-request-into-vba-xml-object-in-ms-access . So if you know anything in respective any help is welcome. By the way the EncodeBase64 I found in another post from you, however I am not sure in which cases it is necessary...

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not yet available it seems like a loop to wait for results works

```
While objRequest.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
```

Besides that access to the webservice works from vba. Another problem is the implementation of the Authorization Header which is probably a formatting problem that I will clearify in another post.