# Vba for Visio 2019

Tags: json, vba, visio

I need help to create VBA for Visio 2019
I will use JSON and I want to populate shape data from JSON requests.

I have only one input http://test.com/(user-defined output)
And 3 or more data points from JSON requests.

Thanks in advance.
EDIT 1:
I managed to get data from the api. Can we use this code in vba in visio?

```html
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("test")),
    Data0 = Json.Document(Web.Contents("test)),
    dataset = Data0[dataset],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(dataset, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"data", "meas", "label", "fill", "pointRadius", "borderWidth", "backgroundColor", "borderColor", "label2"}, {"Column1.data", "Column1.meas", "Column1.label", "Column1.fill", "Column1.pointRadius", "Column1.borderWidth", "Column1.backgroundColor", "Column1.borderColor", "Column1.label2"}),
    #"Expanded Column1.data" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1.data"),
    #"Expanded Column1.data1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1.data", "Column1.data", {"y", "t"}, {"Column1.data.y", "Column1.data.t"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Column1.data1",{"Column1.label", "Column1.data.y", "Column1.meas", "Column1.data.t", "Column1.fill", "Column1.pointRadius", "Column1.borderWidth", "Column1.backgroundColor", "Column1.borderColor", "Column1.label2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Column1.data.t", "Column1.fill", "Column1.pointRadius", "Column1.borderWidth", "Column1.backgroundColor", "Column1.borderColor", "Column1.label2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Please note that SO is not a code writing service. You are to make your own research/attempt and ask a question here (with your code attempt) if you are stuck on a specific issue with your code for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Raymond i will try by my self.

Comment: For starter - 1) I assume you are doing API call to get the JSON response, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246789/how-do-we-use-restful-apis-from-excel-macros-vba) and [this article](https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/vba-http-get-requests-api-serverxmlhttp60/) as a guide on how to call API (or just google for it, there's plenty of examples), consult your API documentation for the endpoints and required parameters/headers 2) You can use [JSONConverter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to help you convert JSON string into a `Dictionary`.